# iPhone Audio App not entering sleep mode

Tags: ios

I am using Matt Gallagher AudioStreamer to stream audio from the network. I specified "App plays audio" and "Application does not run in background -> NO". My app is playing audio in background and everything is working fine.

The problem is **the app is NOT entering sleep mode** and is always awake whether the app is playing the audio or not.

Is this because "App plays audio" specified? How do I make it to behave like normal apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not realize that I was running the app from XCode. Once I disconnected the phone from XCode and ran the app it is entering sleep mode.

Comment: Can you accept your answer so the question no longer shows as active?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable the idle timer, simply set the `idleTimerDisabled` property of your application to `NO`. If this does not work as expected, check the source of the AudioStreamer library, maybe it disables it somewhere.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];`